# Extensive Recursion Tutorial

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Some problems that require recursion have always put me in a fix. I am not always able to come up with a recursive algorithm, but I know that there is a recursive solution to the problem.

I find problems like factorial and fibonacci easy to implement using recursive approach. But when I face more complex problems such as generating the partition of a number http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29, I know that there is a possible recursive approach but I get stuck right there. I can't devise a recursive algorithm. Suppose I want to print all combinations of a string or if I want to bruteforce a Coin Change problem using recursion, I can't devise a recursive approach.

Is there any particular way to think so as to come up with a recursive approach? Is there any extensive recursive algorithms tutorial out there which can help me solve more advanced problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look through the **[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)**, which is highly recommended here on Stack Overflow and is freely available online. It uses the Scheme programming language to teach fundamental concepts about programming. Since Scheme is a functional programming language, recursion is widely used everywhere - not only where you would use it even in imperative programming languages such as C or PHP, but also where you would typically use a looping construct. **The examples and problems in the book present recursion in its natural habitat, if you will, and not through convoluted made-up scenarios.**

Comment: Thank You. I will definitely go through the book :-)

Comment: Actually there is also the full series of video lessons online on the MIT website: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/ They are quite interesting :)